# Laravel / Eloquent : hasManyThrough WHERE

Tags: php, laravel, relational-database, eloquent

In the documentation of Eloquent it is said that I can pass the keys of a desired relationship to **[hasManyThrough](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#has-many-through)**.

Lets say I have Models named Country, User, Post. A Country model might have many Posts through a Users model. That said I simply could call:

```
$this->hasManyThrough('Post', 'User', 'country_id', 'user_id');
```

This is fine so far! **But how can I get these posts only for the user with the id of 3 ?**

Can anybody help here?

Comment: Setup relation on the `User` model and get posts for the user you want. Or query the relation using `has` method. Or use query builder.. Ask precise question to get accurate answer

Comment: Honestly all your suggestions sound interesting. I am just looking for a way to accomplish that and do not know how to ask more precisly =(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So here it goes:

models: `Country` has many `User` has many `Post`

This allows us to use `hasManyThrough` like in your question:

```
// Country model
public function posts()
{
  return $this->hasManyThrough('Post', 'User', 'country_id', 'user_id');
}
```

You want to get posts of a given user for this relation, so:

```
$country = Country::first();
$country->load(['posts' => function ($q) {
  $q->where('user_id', '=', 3);
}]);
// or
$country->load(['posts' => function ($q) {
  $q->has('user', function ($q) {
    $q->where('users.id', '=', 3);
  });
})

$country->posts; // collection of posts related to user with id 3
```

---

**BUT** it will be easier, more readable and more eloquent if you use this instead:
(since it has nothing to do with country when you are looking for the posts of user with id 3)

```
// User model
public function posts()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Post');
}

// then
$user = User::find(3);
// lazy load
$user->load('posts');
// or use dynamic property
$user->posts; // it will load the posts automatically
// or eager load
$user = User::with('posts')->find(3);

$user->posts; // collection of posts for given user
```

To sum up: `hasManyThrough` is a way to get nested relation directly, ie. all the posts for given country, but rather not to search for specific `through` model.

Comment: Great thanks a lot! Btw: The example was taken from the eloquent documentation site. I totally agree with you!

Comment: Did not know eagerloading can do that too

Answer (score 6):

```
$user_id = 3;

$country = Country::find($country_id);

$country->posts()->where('users.id', '=', $user_id)->get();
```

Answer (score 4):

`$this->hasManyThrough('Post', 'User', 'country_id', 'user_id')->where(column,x);`

What happen here is you get the collection in return you can put any condition you want at the end.