# Laravel 4: HasManyThrough. How to access elements with where?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get the chapters, that have been created by an Author in the last year.

Therefor I have an Author, Book and Chapter Model.

I get to the chapters, through a hasManyThrough-Relationship, which looks in my Author-Model like this:

```
public function chapters() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Chapter', 'Book');
}
```

Everything works fine, because now I can do stuff like this: $authors->chapters

But I want to get every chapter from an author, that has been created in the last year:

```
$chapter[$i] = $author->chapters()->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subdays(365));
```

The problem is, that it is not getting the 'created_at' from the chapter, but the 'created_at' from the Author.

If I try something like this:

```
$chapters = $author->chapters;
```

And then try:

```
$chapter = $chapters->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subdays(365));
```

I get the message: 'Can't use Where on a non-object' or something like that.

Any help would be appreciated, on how to access the chapters from the last year. Thanks in advance.

As I read in this post, I got the feeling, that it isn't possible, without being uneloquent. I might be wrong here: 
[Laravel / Eloquent : hasManyThrough WHERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24388688/laravel-eloquent-hasmanythrough-where)

EDIT:
Here are all my Models, Controllers and Migrations:

http://help.laravel.io/193c1da926554da8448cad1cc3289535acc53574

Comment: Sorry I just had to delete my answer. `withTimestamps()` can only be called on `hasMany()` or `belongsToMany()` relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$chapters = $author->chapters();
```

and then

```
echo '<pre>';
dd($chapters->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subdays(365))->get());
```

specify the column names on the hasmanythrough relation

```
public function chapters()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Chapter', 'Book', 'author_id', 'book_id');
}
```

Comment: Thx. I still get an Error that states "Integrity constraint violation: 1052". Further research stated, that I am calling a column name, that appears also in other tables and I therefore have to specify the table. Not sure, if this is correct, since I don't know how to specify a table name, when using the "where" method

Comment: btw. I added in my EDIT in my OP all my controllers, models and migrations

Comment: replace `created_at` by `chapters.created_at` in `where` method

Comment: It should already be reading the chapter's created_at value should it not?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to eager load you relationship with constraint ( recommended as you alleviate the N + 1 query problem)

```
$author = Author::find(1);

// eager loading
$author->load(array('chapters' => function ($query)
{
    $query->where('chapters.created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subdays(365))->get();
}));

// Get chapters of an author
$chapters = author->chapters;
```