# Laravel search based on foreign key from a different table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I have three tables post,user and country.
Post is saved by user who is from a country.
Now I want to search all posts of all users from a country.

so user will filter by country and I get country code from search box to controller `$request->input($country);`

Here are my model relationships:

POST MODEL:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';

    protected $dates = ['status_change'];

    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Photo::class,'post');
    }

    public function make_rel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Make::class, 'make_id' ,'id','make_logo');
    }

    public function user_rel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'created_by' ,'id');
    }

}
```

COUNTRY MODEL:

```
class Country extends Model
{
    public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

USER MODEL:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{


    public function country_rel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class, 'country' ,'country_code');
    }
}
```

SEARCH FUNCTION

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'country' => 'required',
    ]);

    $country = Country::where('country_name',$request->input('country'))->get();
    $data = Post::where('created_by',$country->user_rel->name)
    ->get();
    dd($data);
}
```

This is not working. Could anyone advise what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [hasManyThrugh](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through). The documentation even uses your exact use case:

```php
    class Country extends Model
    {
        public function users(){
            return $this->hasMany('App\User');
        }

        public function posts() {
            return $this->hasManyThrough(
                'App\Post',
                'App\User',
                'country_id', // Foreign key on users table...
                'user_id', // Foreign key on posts table...
                'id', // Local key on countries table...
                'id' // Local key on users table...
            );
        }

    }
```

Comment: and here's how to make a query out of it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24388688/laravel-eloquent-hasmanythrough-where